# SharePoint:CssRegistration not working without master page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need add style sheet to my application page using **SharePoint:CssRegistration**, but becose my page don't have an master page, the CssRegistration don't work, and the page come without style sheet link. how can I fix this?

it seem there is missing elegant, I should add to the page, what is this element?

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewSite.Project.Server.Layouts.Employee"  %>

<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/style Library/style.css%>" runat="server" />


<div  class="myclass">
   text
</div>
```

Comment: Is Publishing feature enabled on your site? Without that the tokens such as `~SiteCollection` will not work.

Comment: yes, I found the missing element, I need to add <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15" />